# Setting Dependencies/Triggers in bamboo?

Tags: automation, dependencies, bamboo

Im wondering if I can get some help in relation to Bamboo. I am very very new to this system.

I am able to make plans etc but now I need to Automate 1 of those plans instead of manually kicking it off.

Unlike the other plans I cant time it to go off. As it is depend on 2 other plans finishing first

The setup currently for the plan is this

Plan 1 must pass and finish & Plan 2 must pass and finish (Both are already triggered by a set time)

Then we can run the Plan 3 (Must check that both Plan 1 and Plan 2 are finished and passed)

**So my question is, is there a way to automate the plan so it follows the conditions above**

*Note the plan should only run once both plans are finished, not only when one finish's*

Any help you can give would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dependency tree is usually setup as a parent triggering one or more child plans.

In this case you could set the three plans to build sequentially - Plan 1 completion triggers Plan 2, and Plan 2 completion triggers Plan 3. The downside is a longer overall time to build, and Plan 2 would not build if Plan 1 fails.

Dependencies are setup in the Dependencies tab of the Plan configuration. The Parent triggers the children. In the Advanced settings you can configure blocking strategies to stop child builds commencing until the Parent completes.

Further information is available on the [Bamboo Dependency Help Page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BAMBOO/Setting+up+plan+build+dependencies)

Comment: See the problem there is that plan 3 can only run when both of the other plans are finished currently plan 1 and 2 are trigger by a set time so they dont need anything done to them, I just need a way of kicking off plan 3 when plan 1 and 2 finish and pass ?

Comment: You can automate all the plans to build sequentially, but the dependencies will break if you must run plan 1 and 2 in parallel because defining the same plan 3 child on both parents dependency tabs will trigger plan 3 whenever either parent finishes (rather than both).

Comment: what about setting triggers ?

Comment: Repository triggers should work as you need them to if your three plans are triggered by changes in the same source repository. 
Timer triggers on the other hand appear to run independently and even if you set the timer trigger for Plan 3 to only build if Plans 1 and/or 2 are successful, Plan 3 will still commence while Plans 1 and/or 2 are still building (as long as their previous builds were successful). I don't think timer triggers will solve your issue.

Comment: Another possibility... if your plans are simple... would be to combine them into a single plan. Plan 1 and Plan 2 would become jobs in the first stage, and Plan 3 would be a job in the second stage. The first stage will run the two jobs in parallel, followed by the second stage.

Comment: I believe the plans are simple enough with bamboo do I have to build the plans again or is there way of calling or dropping those plans into a a new build lets call it Mega Plan ??

Comment: No. All you can do is clone one of the plans and create the other stages and jobs inside it manually.

Comment: hmm, well right now Plan 1 and 2 have two stages each that have to be kept separate is it possible to do that ?

Comment: It might be possible but I think the better solution given Bamboos limitations in this area is to build your three existing plans in sequence using dependency triggers. My suggestion to combine the plans is only feasible for very simple builds. As your plans have multiple stages I think combining them will create unneeded complexity and may cause heartache in maintenance and understanding of the plans in future.

Comment: Hey was wondering if u could help with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30234328/using-bamboo-inline-scripting